# Prove that $\sin(z_{1}+z_{2})=\sin z_{1} \cos z_{2} + \cos z_{1} \sin z_{2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Prove that $\sin(z_{1}+z_{2})=\sin z_{1} \cos z_{2} + \cos z_{1} \sin z_{2}$

**My solution**

Let $z_{2}$ be a fixed real number. Then, $f(z)=\sin(z + z_{2})$ and $g(z)=\sin z\cos z_{2}+\cos z\sin z_{2}$ are two entire functions (of $z$) which agree for all real values $z=z_{1}$ and, hence, for all complex values $z=z_{1}$, as well.

Let $z=z_{1}$ be any such complex number. Then, $f(z)=\sin(z_{1}+z)$ and $g(z)=\sin z_{1}\cos z+\cos z_{1}\sin z$ agree for all real values $z=z_{2}$ and, hence,for all complex values $z=z_{2}$ as well.

Is my method correct?

Comment: How do you know, in the second step, that the equality holds for all real values of $z$? (In the first step, you know the equality holds because you know the identity is true when both variables are real)

Comment: Mariano, did s/he not prove exactly that in the first step?

Comment: This looks fine, and can be streamlined if you know a little about holomorphic functions of several complex variables. In particular, $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a set of uniqueness for entire function of two variables, just as $\mathbb{R}$ is a set of uniqueness in the one variable setting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An alternative:

$$\begin{align*}
\sin z&= \dfrac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}\\
\cos z&= \dfrac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}.
\end{align*}$$

Now substitute into $\sin(z_1)\cos(z_2)+\sin(z_2)\cos(z_1)$, expand, and simplify.